# How to add external css file in html file design

Tags: master-page, design-manager

I used design manager to create Master Page. it was created without error or warning and i did apply it to pages.

I want to add custom css file to master page as this block code

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration3" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/StyleLibrary/ABC/css/SP.ABC.Main.css %>" runat="server" />
```

As you know, the problem when using `<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration3" Name="/StyleLibrary/ABC/css/SP.ABC.Main.css" runat="server" />` is that the url of this css file is uncorrect when sitecollection is created with explicitly named path (for example, `http://server/sites/team`).

I used snippet generator in design manager to generate the code block and embed to my html design file, but it would throw exception at the very line i place the code block.

```
<!--CS: Start Create Snippets From Custom ASP.NET Markup Snippet-->
<!--SPM:  <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration3" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/StyleLibrary/ABC/css/SP.ABC.Main.css %>" runat="server" />-->
<!--CE: End Create Snippets From Custom ASP.NET Markup Snippet-->
```

Could you tell me the workaround for this case? another way to place external css file that will work in any cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<MS>` and `<ME>` tags which denote the beginning and end of a SharePoint control or a snippet. The `<SPM>` tag ("SharePoint markup") which you have used actually is used for registering a SharePoint namespace. So, the code should be:

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration3" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/StyleLibrary/ABC/css/SP.ABC.Main.css %>" runat="server" />-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
```

**UPDATE**

Try replacing `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `%&gt;`. That is

```
Name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/StyleLibrary/ABC/css/SP.ABC.Main.css %&gt;"
```

See more at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I tried `<!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/ABC/Responsive/css/bootstrap3.min.css %>" runat="server" > --><!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->`
but still get error from this line of code.

Comment: See updated answer.